# How to know what to do in order to complete a quest?

Tags: divinity-original-sin

So I recently started playing Divinity: Original Sin.

Definitely a favorite game so far, but I'm becoming flustered when trying to figure out ***what to do*** to complete a quest.

For example, it may say in the Journal "We should talk to Mr. Smith".

Unlike some other RPGs there is no "arrow/marker" for the next objective. Am I supposed to simply wander around until I bump into this "Mr. Smith"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typically the conversation in which you are told to find *Mr. Smith* will also give you some information about where to find him. Conversations are also recorded in the Journal, so you can always go and look there if you weren't paying attention as they took place.

In some cases, being on the right step of a quest will also add a dialogue option where you can ask folk for Mr. Smith's whereabouts.

If you just can't find the bugger, don't worry too much and just go explore a bit, you might just bump into him, or something else to distract you. In some cases quests stretch across multiple cities and it'll be a long time before you find who you're looking for.

Comment: I did not actually realize you could view conversations, thank you for sharing that!